# Negative complex number in exponent

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

can I get some help for proving that $z^{-w} = \frac{1}{z^w}$ where $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$ for any branch of the logarithm

*sorry for the formation not sure how to write math types here yet*

Comment: Enclose your things in \$ signs

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Doing that, one gets $z^(-w) = 1/z^w$.

Comment: What have you  tried please provide more context

Comment: I tried using $ z^(-w)=e^(-wlogz)$ and the same for $1/z^w$ hoping i would end up to two equals sets but i don't think It works.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z^{-w}=k$ 
Then taking ln on both sides, 
$ln(z^{-w})=-wlnz=ln k$ 
Since $-wlnz=wln\frac{1}{z}=lnk$ 
We get $k=\frac{1}{z}^w$